# I have to create two threads of schedulers and I'm getting a segmentation fault in my code but I can't see why that is. Anybody able to help out?

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, segmentation-fault

Okay, so my code right now is a little messy and not optimal at all so apologies for that (I'll clean it up once it's working).

But basically I have to implement a longterm and shortterm scheduler as queues and the elements are structs (process). Each scheduler is invoked using multithreading, but when i try to run the longtermscheduler i get a segmentation fault and i'm not sure why. i had to create another struct because pthread only takes one input for the function it's turning into a thread and i need to provide it with both queues. I think the issue is somewhere there but I just don't see what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

These are my structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct Queue
{
    struct Process *front, *rear;
};

struct Process
{
    int pid, time;
    struct Process* next;
};

struct args {
    struct Queue* jqueue;
    struct Queue* rqueue;
};
```

These are functions for the queue

```
struct Process* newProcess(int i)
{
    struct Process* temp = (struct Process*)malloc(sizeof(struct Process));
    temp->pid = i;
    temp->time = (rand() % 30) + 1;
    return temp;
}

struct Queue* createQueue()
{
    struct Queue* queue = (struct Queue*) malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    queue->front = queue->rear = NULL;
    return queue;
}

void enqueue(struct Queue* queue, struct Process* proc)
{
    if (queue->rear == NULL)
    {
        queue->front = queue->rear = proc;
        return;
    }

    queue->rear->next = proc;
    queue->rear = proc;
}

struct Process* dequeue(struct Queue* queue)
{
    if (queue->front == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    struct Process* temp = queue->front;
    queue->front = queue->front->next;
    if (queue->front == NULL)
    {
        queue->rear = NULL;
    }
    return temp;
}

int getSize(struct Process* front)
{
    int count = 0;
    struct Process* current = front;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is the longtermscheduler function which should be run as a separate thread. it moves elements from jobqueue to readyqueue

```
void *longTermScheduler(void *input)
{
    sleep(1);
    struct Process* current = ((struct args*)input)->jqueue->front;
    printf("%d", current->pid);
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("[LTS] Job Queue: [Process %d: Time %d], ", current->pid, current->time);
        current = current->next;
    }

    current = ((struct args*)input)->rqueue->front;
    if((getSize(current)) == 0)
    {
        printf("[LTS] Ready Queue: EMPTY");
    }
    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
        {
        printf("[LTS] Ready Queue: [Process %d: Time %d], ", current->pid, current->time);
        current = current->next;
        }
    }

    int c = getSize(((struct args*)input)->rqueue->front);
    while(c < 6)
    {
        struct Process* temp = dequeue(((struct args*)input)->rqueue);
        enqueue(((struct args*)input)->rqueue, temp);
        printf("[LTS] Process %d removed from the Job Queue and inserted to the Ready Queue", temp->pid);
        c++;
    }
    printf("[LTS] Ready Queue is Full, cannot enter more.");

    current = ((struct args*)input)->jqueue->front;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("[LTS] Job Queue: [Process %d: Time %d], ", current->pid, current->time);
        current = current->next;
    }

    current = ((struct args*)input)->rqueue->front;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("[LTS] Ready Queue: [Process %d: Time %d], ", current->pid, current->time);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

main function

```
int main()
{
    int n = 1;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    struct Queue* jobqueue = createQueue();
    struct Queue* readyqueue = createQueue();

    struct args *queues = (struct args *)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    queues->jqueue = jobqueue;
    queues->rqueue = readyqueue;

    while(n <= 11)
    {
        struct Process* newproc = newProcess(n);
        enqueue(jobqueue, newproc);
        n++;
    }

    struct Process* current = jobqueue->front;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("[Kernel] Process %d created with Time = %d\n", current->pid, current->time);
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("[Kernel] Long Term Scheduler Invoked\n");
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, longTermScheduler, (void *)queues);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that your `newProcess()` function doesn't initialize the value of `next` to a null pointer; this leaves it with garbage and is pretty much asking for trouble even if you set it properly later.  When you allocate a new object, set *all* the fields to sane values.

Comment: Another suggestion: `longTermScheduler()` receives a generic `void *` parameter, but the code uses it as a `struct args *` and casts it that way every time.  This is tedious, so recommend assigning a local variable early in the function, assign and cast the parameter to the type you need, and then use *that* throughout.  This makes it much easier to read (though no more correct).

Comment: Also, the `printf()` calls do not generally have `\n` newlines at the end, and due to stdio buffering, many of these calls won't be flushed to output so even the venerable "printf debugging" technique doesn't help much. Recommend adding newlines to the end of all your printf strings that intend to be full lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll implement them. Update: I managed to get it to work a little by added '/n' to the printf statements. But it still does a segmentation fault after printing the jqueue and goes into print the rqueue

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is, and you can **totally** find this yourself with the debugger; this is a necessary skill for this kind of software development.  Compile your code with the `-g` flag to `gcc`, then run the debugger as `gdb ./a.out`, then type `run` to run the code.  It will show you the very line that it's faulting on; there are at least two fault-causing errors to fix.

Comment: 0x0000000000400a11 in longTermScheduler (input=0x602050) at newidea.c:149
149                     printf("[LTS] Process %d removed from the Job Queue and inserted to the Ready Queue", temp->pid);

So that's what I got, I'm assuming it's some form of deadlock? I'm not quite certain.

Comment: Yes. We are pretty sure that `printf` itself is not the problem, but under what circumstances would `temp->pid` cause a problem?  It's definitely not deadlock. Where does that `temp` pointer come from?

Comment: Oh man, I was trying to dequeue an empty rqueue when it should be jqueue! Thanks a lot for your help! And also showing me about the debugger, I had completely forgot about that.

Comment: Yes you were :-)   Keep going and find the other similar issue, and you'll really have cemented the value of a debugger to point you where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP found the problem via comments above, but there are some code suggestions that would make things much easier to read.

First is some advice about `malloc()`. You should always assume that the resulting chunk of memory contains junk, so you should always initialize the important stuff. The `temp->next` pointer was not initialized, and that almost for sure caused problems.

Also, it's not necessary to cast the result of `malloc()` because the `void *` pointer converts to any other kind of data pointer automatically.

And though you can get the size via the type *name*, it's better to derive it from the variable it's going to. `sizeof *temp` means "the # of bytes of what `temp` points to", so the size will always be correct even if you change `Process` to some other type.

```
struct Process* newProcess(int i)
{
    struct Process* temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    temp->pid = i;
    temp->time = (rand() % 30) + 1;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

In the `longTermScheduler` function, there's a lot of casting going on that doesn't need to be:

```
void *longTermScheduler(void *tempInput)
{
    struct args *input = tempInput;
    ...
```

Now `input` is no longer a void pointer you have to cast all over the place, but a real pointer to the real type you care about, so you can use it directly. This is much easier all through the code, as the next snippet will show.

The final point, one that directly weighs in on the bug you found, there are too many places in the code where you're trusting that you're getting a valid pointer.

```
// in longTermScheduler
    ...
    int c = getSize(input->rqueue->front);
    while(c < 6)
    {
        struct Process* temp = dequeue(input->rqueue);
        if (temp == NULL) break;  // CAREFUL HERE!
        enqueue(input->rqueue, temp);
        printf("[LTS] Process %d removed from the Job Queue and inserted to the Ready Queue\n", temp->pid);
        c++;
    }
```

I think you suggested that it should have pulled from the job queue and not the ready queue, but the bug is the same: not checking for a valid pointer gives unhappy surprises, as you have seen.